How to pack the pyav.packet and distribute to another computer
I'm currently working on projects which needs to read frames from RTSP server on single entry of computer, do some preprocessing and distribute these frames with preprocessed metadata to different backend for different purpose.
And after googling, I found that PyAV could be the solution which can retrieve the video from RTSP source and make it packets, which could possibly be sent to another computer.
Considering the network bandwidth, transmit the packets instead of the decoded frames could be better choice.
But now comes the problem, socket/MQ, usually only allows to send bytes or string.
Encode the PyAV.packet.Packet object into byte is easy by bytes(packet), but I couldn't find out the way to decode it back to PyAV.packet.Packet object.
I've tried to use pickle to serialize the packet, but this method is not implemented in PyAV, and was rejected by the official team.
I've also tried to use another package called msgpack, which also failed to serialize the packet.
I've tried the following code after reading the source code of PyAV
packet_bytes = bytes(packet)
pt = av.packet.Packet(len(packet_bytes))
pt.update(packet_bytes)

the update function seems did not update anything
Is there anyway to decode the bytes back to packet object?
Or, can someone give out a way to encode the frame packet and the preprocessed metadata (which is differ frame by frame) together (like H264 SEI Message, which I tried, but could not be inserted when using Python) then send to backend?

that's not how to do this. pick a container format, mux your packets, send that off. or learn about video streaming protocols.

packet_bytes = bytes(packet)
pt = av.packet.Packet(packet_bytes)
This worked for us.

Receiving packets from a RTSP camera and producing them in a kafka broker would be like this:
import av
from kafka import KafkaProducer

url = "rtsp://username:password@ip:554/live"
options = {
  'analyzeduration': str(5000000*2.0), # Analyze up to 5 seconds
  'probesize': str(5000000), # Read up to 5 MB
  'rtsp_transport': "tcp",
}
container = av.open(url, mode="r", options=options, timeout=2.0)
if len(container.streams.video) == 0: raise Exception("No stream")
container.streams.video[0].thread_type = "AUTO"  # Go faster!
packets = iter(container.demux())
producer = KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers=["ip:port"], acks=1)
for packet in packets:
  bpacket = bytes(packet, "utf-8") if isinstance(packet, str) else bytes(packet)
  producer.send(
        "topic",
        value=bpacket,
        key=bytes("stream_packet", "utf-8")
  )

Consuming those packets again and have a video stream of them:
import av
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition

W = 1920
H = 1080
de_codec = "h264"
pix_fmt = "yuv420p"
log_level = "ANY"
chunks = []
topic = "topic"
bootstrap_servers = ["ip:port"]

ctx = av.codec.context.CodecContext.create(de_codec, "r")  # type: ignore
if W != None:
  ctx.width = W
if H != None:
  ctx.height = H
if pix_fmt != None:
  ctx.pix_fmt = pix_fmt


consumer = KafkaConsumer(client_id="abc", group_id="abc",
                         bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)
consumer.assign([TopicPartition(topic, 0)])
consumer.seek_to_end()
try:
  for msg in consumer:
    chunk = msg.value
    packets = ctx.parse(chunk)
    if not packets:
      continue
    for packet in packets:
      try:
        frames = ctx.decode(packet)
        if not frames:
          continue
        for frame in frames:
          frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24")
      except Exception as e:
        continue
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print(f"Total number of {n}, fps {1/fps}, size {size/1024} KB")
  exit(0)

